# Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView

Tags: android, xml, layout-inflater

I am getting below error and problem is that I don’t see any familiar names or my classes in the error message nor in stack trace. The other difficulty is that I still cannot reproduce this crash on my devices, so I don’t know what action may cause it.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
   at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ListMenuPresenter.java:102)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState.getListMenuView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1908)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initializePanelContent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1203)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.openPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1045)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyUpPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1410)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyUp(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:877)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:871)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:226)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1876)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:4196)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4139)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3199)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5427)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ListMenuPresenter.java:102)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState.getListMenuView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1908)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initializePanelContent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1203)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.openPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1045)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyUpPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1410)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyUp(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:877)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:871)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:226)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1876)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:4196)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4139)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3199)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5427)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01012b a=4}
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2343)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:604)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:810)
       at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:147)
       at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:143)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView.<init>(ExpandedMenuView.java:54)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView.<init>(ExpandedMenuView.java:50)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ListMenuPresenter.java:102)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState.getListMenuView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1908)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initializePanelContent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1203)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.openPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1045)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyUpPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1410)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyUp(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:877)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:871)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:226)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1876)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:4196)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4139)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3199)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5427)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is full stack trace? `InflateException` always caused by another exception.

Comment: @llyaGulya: Please check added the full stack trace

Comment: You are adding resource which is either not drawable or is not accessible or may be you are inserting it wrongly. Share your java class in which you are trying to add this view and also your xml file.

Comment: @Anus: I am not able find the class name in above stack trace,can you please help me. Above is the complete stack trace

Comment: Class which is throwing error is android built-in class android.view.*, you have to see where in your application have you included this view and see its corresponding xml file respectively.

Comment: I'm getting the same report from Samsung GT-S5301L, Android 4. It maybe an error in Samsung's port of Android.

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev : Have find the solution of this issue

Comment: No, my app is still crashing sometimes. All crashes received from Android 4.0.3/4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong resource in your xml. Probably you are trying to use color resource as a drawable (i.e. `@color/` instead of `@drawable/`.
If you can not reproduce it yourself, you can recheck your xml and replace any color usage with drawable one.
Also, it might be because you put your drawable in wrong folder (i.e. `drawable-v21` and trying to run application on API 19)
Thus, recheck your xml.